# Issue burning a Live CD on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, centos, iso-image, livecd

I've downloaded the Live CD for CentOS 6.4, here: http://centos.mirror.nac.net/6.4/isos/x86_64/

The .iso I'm using is 702MB, the first one listed.

I download it to my desktop, send it to the CD drive, and right click to burn it onto CD. There are no other files being burned, just the one .iso.

I get this error:

[image]

Is Windows 8 really unable to calculate the size correctly? Is there a way to bypass this and proceed to burn my Live CD?

Edit: Here are the properties of the file being burned:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try free [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download) - it has never let me down.

Answer (score 0):

I used "Free ISO burner" and was able to burn the image successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a CD the default size will be 700mb, since your file size is 702mb, this might be an issue. Try using a DVD that might work, but of-course the remaining space will be waste. 
    Also try using different software to burn. Here are few suggestions.
 http://www.poweriso.com/download.htm
 http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm